# How to program so that different processes run on different CPU cores?

Tags: c, linux, multiprocessing

I'm writing a linux C program with 2 processes. I will run the program on different  machines.

These machine may have multiple CPU cores.

When I run the program, will the system allocate different CPU core for different processes? or I need to write some codes so as to fully utilize the CPU cores?

Comment: Yes, unless to do something to prevent it, the kernel will schedule processes onto all cores. To use multiple cores in a single program, you typically use multiple threads (though this can sometimes be implicit, such as using OpenMp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to pin threads/processes to specific CPUs then you have to use the `sched_setaffinity(2)` system call or the `pthread_setaffinity_np(3)` library call for that. Each core in Linux has it's own virtual CPU ID.

These calls allow you to set the allowed CPU mask.

Otherwise it will be up to the digression of the scheduler to run your threads where it feels like running them.

Neither will guarantee that your process runs in parallel though. This is something only the scheduler can decide unless you run realtime.

Here is some sample code:

```
#include <sched.h>

int run_on_cpu(int cpu) {

    cpu_set_t allcpus;

    CPU_ZERO(&allcpus);
    sched_getaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &allcpus);

    int num_cpus = CPU_COUNT(&allcpus);

    fprintf(stderr, "%d cpus available for scheduling\nAvailable CPUs: ", num_cpus);

    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < CPU_SETSIZE; i++) {
        if (CPU_ISSET(i, &allcpus))
            fprintf(stderr, "%zu, ", i);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");

    if (CPU_ISSET(cpu, &allcpus)) {
        cpu_set_t cpu_set;
        CPU_ZERO(&cpu_set);
        CPU_SET(cpu, &cpu_set);
        return pthread_setaffinity_np(pthread_self(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpu_set);
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure who downvotes this answer, but it's a fair answer. If someone wants to pin a task on a particular CPU this is the way to go, unless you don't want scheduler to decide. +1

Comment: @rakib Cheers. I never understood how people can downvote anyways without at least commenting on what is wrong.